# Automatically updating GET request python

Tags: python, refresh

I have a exchange rate request that I would like to update every second.  As of now I have to re-load the program to refresh the rate.  How would I go about doing this in Python?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance..

script:

```
import oandapy

oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxxxxxxxx")

response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
prices = response.get("prices")
asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")

stop = asking_price - .001
```

Per answer:

```
while True:
    response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
    prices = response.get("prices")
    asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")

    stop = asking_price - .001

time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general method is to wrap the entire thing in an infinite loop, and wait between requests:

```
while True:
    # ... do and print request
    time.sleep(1) # then wait one second
```

Make sure that your API access token allows sending a request every second.

---

However, after a quick Google I found that the API you're using supports streaming rates: https://github.com/oanda/oandapy#rates-streaming

Comment: I am actually using that as well, however, I was having extreme difficulty parsing the stream to give me a rate I could use for a variable stop loss price.  Thanks for the help!  I'm trying it now

Comment: This seems to work, however, I am getting this error:  oandapy.OandaError: OANDA API returned error code 68 (Rate limit violation of newly established connections. Allowed rate: 2 connections per second) how could I throttle the request?  Thanks again

Comment: @user2883183 Increase the sleep time between requests.

Comment: No matter what I set it to I still get the same error..  I think this answered my question though.  Thanks for the help!